# Discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I am trying to make a bot where the user gives an argument called url. This url is the link to the spotify playlist that they want the bot to play music from. This all has worked with no issues for a long time until I tried it out yesterday and suddenly it doesn't work anymore.

This is what the code looks like:

```
// Search for the playlist using the discord-player
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
            const playlistResult = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
            })
```

Now the error message says that the error is on the line of  `const playlistResult = await client.player.search(url, {`

So I thought that maybe url was undefined or interaction.user was, but even after setting them both manually it still gave the same error as said in the title.

What makes it even more weird is that I have other commands similar to this added to my bot (such as just playing a single song). And that works 100% fine without any errors.

What am I missing? How do I fix the error?

This is the whole error message:

```
16.02 19:44:43 [Bot] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
16.02 19:44:43 [Bot] at Player.search (/node_modules/discord-player/dist/Player.js:369:54)
16.02 19:44:43 [Bot] at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
16.02 19:44:43 [Bot] at async Object.execute (/Bot1/commands/spotify.js:66:36)
16.02 19:44:43 [Bot] at async Client.<anonymous> (/Bot1/index.js:177:9)
```

(spotify.js is the script)

Comment: _"What am I missing?"_ Including the whole error message. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with one of the tracks in a playlist it tried to play. One example of it, you can [see here](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-playlist-tracks/?playlist_id=571OWCRxZMCGVL4Ste9FVw&market=&fields=&limit=1&offset=338&additional_types=track). (But music bots are prohibited by Spotify though.)